# Nested search filters

Tags: search, filter

I'm designing a new filter on my search page, however, I'm slightly concerned it's over-elaborate. Below is a screenshot of the filter. I've had to replace the real values with fake data.

[image]

[image]

How the search works:

**New search 1:**

Checking 'Online' will run the search. Once the search has run the nested options (Browser types), which are hidden by default, will be displayed.

**New search 2:**

Clicking on the chevron next to 'Online' will not run a search, instead, this will reveal the nested options. If one of the options are checked then a search will be run.

The nested options are hidden to save space.

I've added the chevron so users can easily refine their search, without having to search on the top-level 'Online' first.

My question is:

Have I over complicated this filter by adding the chevron which reveals the nested options, without running a search. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you've suggested, it would be simpler if the nested options were shown by default as soon as you select 'online'. This would make the additional options more obvious. From your question it sounds like screen space is limited, so you would need to weigh up the importance of the nested options to determine whether this trade off is worthwhile (are they critical to refining the search or more of an 'advanced' search?).

You could also combine this with a change of layout for the initial fields so that you have more space. For example:

[image: Nested search filters v1]

This would show the additional options when 'online' is selected and hide them otherwise.

You could also play around with other input types to make this simpler. E.g.

[image: Nested search filters v2]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar situation where there is a table of results that can be filtered, ordered, and search-refined as well.

I try to make the user interact with these features in the most relevant spot as possible, and I came up with this visual solution.

I hope it might be helpful in your case too.

(See image below)

[image]

This is the userflow:

1. The user searches for something
2. The result page loads and shows the results
3. Within the results of the DB search (server side) there is the opportunity to search within the results (client side)
4. Within the results page users can filter and sort the items shown in the table

---

Let me know if you have any questions.